# Is there any mechanical difference between the phrases, "as a reaction..." and "can use your reaction..."?

Tags: dnd-5e, reactions

I was reading *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* when I stumbled on an interesting turn of phrase (it's repeated often in the book and in others, but this was where I first realized it).

The [Demonic Boons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mtof/the-blood-war#DemonicBoons) section lists the following trait for followers of Graz'zt (p. 30):

> ***Joy from Pain.*** Whenever this creature suffers a critical hit, it can make one melee weapon attack **as a reaction**.

[Emphasis mine]

Meanwhile, in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 46), the Mastermind rogue's Misdirection subclass feature says:

> When you are targeted by an attack while a creature within 5 feet of you is granting you cover against that attack, you can **use your reaction** to have the attack target that creature instead of you.

[Emphasis mine]

Is there any mechanical difference between these two phrases? If something is done "as a reaction", does it not "use your reaction"? Or are they just interchangable phrases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Grammar is the only difference

Mechanically these two phrases are identical. Doing something "as a reaction" "use[s] your reaction". They only exist in two forms to make the sentence structure and grammar correct for the various abilities that use them.

#### Third Person vs. Second Person

> [...] **it** can make one melee weapon attack as a reaction.

is a third person description of the action. Whereas,

> [...] **you** can use your reaction [...]

is a second person perspective. Potentially, this the reason for the variations in phrasing. There are contradicting examples however, so this probably isn't the case.

Comment: I like this answer and I think it's correct, since I just now noticed a similar pattern with "use your action" and "as an action," and allowing "as an action" to not burn the creature's action would be absurdly broken. However, I will note that other abilities in Xanathar's use second person and still use "as a reaction", such as the Scout Rogue's Skirmisher Ability on page 47 ("*you may move up to half your speed when an enemy ends its turn within 5 feet of you...*"), so I'm not sure that's the reason. It was a good theory, though.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath ah well. The first part was my main answer. I was just having a guess based on the examples given. I would need to go a analyse a bunch more examples to come up with a better reasoning.